# Why is `this` always the `Window` object in the constructor here?

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
(function() {

  function App(elements, options) {

    if (!this instanceof App) return new App(elements, options);

    var that = this;

    return this;

  }

  window.App = App;

})();

App(document.querySelectorAll('.Slider-slide'), {
  interval: 5000
});
```

My problem is, that it NEVER creates a new instance of `App`, so, `this` further down the code is always the `Window` object, any idea why??

Comment: Because you are not intializing App with a new call

Comment: @megawac not necessary: http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-class-instantiation/

Comment: I provided an example in answers which will make the case true @benhowdle89

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your if condition is the problem:

```
if (!this instanceof App)
```

should be:

```
if (!(this instanceof App))
```

Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table

Answer (score 0):

*Update* as stated in Musa's answer, the code can be corrected with either of these 2 patterns:

```
(function() {

  function App(elements, options) {

    if (!(this instanceof App)) return new App(elements, options);

    var that = this;

  }

  window.App = App;

})();

var myapp = App(document.querySelectorAll('.Slider-slide'), {
  interval: 5000
});
```

This `class` structure does not require the `new` call:

```
(function() {
    function App(elements, options) {
        var that = this;
    }

    //calling window.App(/*stuff*/) will always return a new class
    window.App = function(elements, options) {
        return new App(elements, options);
    };
})();
```

One small note - when you create a class you do not need to return this as this is handled implicitly.

Comment: @benhowdle89 Yes, I misread the code originally, I updated the answer